# Regex search for Smarty template

Tags: php, regex, smarty

I have some fields with names such as:

```
home_phone
company_phone
mobile_phone
other_phone_c
personal_phone_c
```

And I have a Smarty variable to populate input values with the field values:

```
value="{$fields.{{$prefix}}_phone}"
```

But the ones with the suffix `_c` are not outputting, since they don't match the pattern.

Is there a way to append some kind of regex so that it will look for values that either end after the `phone` or with `_c`, something like:

```
{$fields.{{$prefix}}_phone{regex | ($|_c$)}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `.*_(?:phone|phone_c)$`

It will match desired strings, which ends with `_phone` or `phone_c`.

Comment: It has to end in either `_phone` or `_phone_c`.  Would the following work:  `_phone(?:$|_c$)`  ?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting an error:

`syntax error: unrecognized tag: $fields.home_phone(?:$|_c$).value`  Does your solution only work in Smarty 3? Do you have a link to the documentation?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Anthony, I can't test regex in Smarty. I only provide regex using standard syntax.